# Neoclipse Exception - Database Error

Tags: neo4j, neoclipse

I have created nodes and relationships in java using Neo4j jars,I am trying to display the same from Neoclipse,
I am getting Exception when trying to create connection from Neoclipse  to the folder created by java program (I am using windows 7) .
Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException:Mismatching store version found(v0.A.1 while expecting v0.A.0) 
and the store is not cleanly shutdown.
Recover the database with previous database version and then attempt to upgrade .
```

after this i added `graphDb.shutdown();` code then i got different exception:

```
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader$UnableToUpgradeException:
Not all store Files match the version required for successful upgrade.
```

List of jar Files:

geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
 lucene-core-3.6.2.jar
 neo4j-2.0.1.jar
 neo4j-cypher-2.0.1.jar
 neo4j-graph-algo-2.0.1.jar
 neo4j-graph-matching-2.0.1.jar
 neo4j-jmx-2.0.1.jar
 neo4j-kernel-2.0.1.jar
 neo4j-lucene-index-2.0.1.jar
 neo4j-udc-2.0.1.jar

Please guide me.

Comment: Neoclipse has to be upgraded to Neo4j 2.0 first. Sorry

Comment: yes tried to search But latest Neoclipse seems to be 1.9.5 https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neoclipse
How to upgrade it to 2.0 (Windows)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've created your datastore with Neo4j 2.0.1. Neoclipse seems to use an earlier version. Datastore downgrades are not supported.

However you could drop your database into a Neo4j 2.0.1 server and connect to it remotely using Neoclipse.

Comment: I tried using Neo4j 1.9.5 library however it didn't work,DynamcLabel is not there in Neo4j 1.9.5 for that i have to use latest version , which is not compatible with Neoclipse. What can i do to fix this? plz guide